# When using watchposition is it better to use enableHighAccuracy?

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am getting mixed results between an iphone 4 and android smartphone. iphone 4 returns a less accurate position. Also, when permission for location was just granted, watchposition returns an unreliable position around 3km from actual position which makes me believe it's information from the cell towers instead of internet and satellite. If I don't move the device, it doesn't update until for like 1-10 minutes. So I'm thinking of using enableHighAccuracy, turning it to true.

What are the demerit/disadvantages of enabling high accuracy? Does it make watchposition's success callback slower? What happens if the device happens to be in a place which is hard to get location information?

Comment: `instead of internet` - "internet" won't give you any position at all :p - as for your question ... try it

Answer (score 0):

Using enableHighAccuracy can come with increased resource usage, slower response times and increased power consumption, particularly on mobile devices.

As for accuracy, there is no guarantee that enabling enableHighAccuracy will give a better result, it depends on the device. For example, a phone with GPS is more likely to give a preise result than one without it. All enableHighAccuracy tells the browser to do is to give the most accurate response that it can.

See the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PositionOptions/enableHighAccuracy) for more information.